# Avoiding .ASPXAUTH key misuse

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.7) application, I have a login page.

These are the steps I did:

1. I gave user credentials in login page and it is navigated to next page (ex: employee page)
2. Using the DevTool of chrome, I copied the key of `.ASPXAUTH` in cookies.
3. After log off, `.ASPXAUTH`  key and value had disappeared
4. Then I created the `.ASPXAUTH` key manually and pasted the copied value back in cookies
5. Then it navigated next page (employee page) without needing of user credentials

This seems to be concern related to application security. How can I completely avoid this situation?

Comment: What, exactly, do you think the "auth" bit of the cookie name means?